# Get direct URL of images in Document Library and display in column

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a document library in SharePoint online which is used to store photos.

I naively thought that there would be an built-in way to easily get the direct URL for several images but have found the only way is to click each image, then click the "View Original" icon and then copy the link from the new browser window that opens.

This is a big problem for people who want to insert images from this Document Library into Powerpoint (the desktop app, not Powerpoint online)

I would like to add a "Image URL" column to this document library however I don't know how to implement a calculation or code that this column will use to display the images direct URL (and by direct URL I mean something like https://company.sharepoint.com/site/Photo%20Library/2014/Ceremony/event/Web001_MG_7721.jpg)

Many thanks,

Robin

Answer (score 1):

As you are using SharePoint online, you can directly share the picture with a anonymous link using the copy link button in Modern experience. The link can be used directly in PowerPoint desktop app per my test. Make sure you have enabled external sharing in the admin center.

Here is a tutorial:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off
[image]

Update:
Use this workflow you can get the Direct URL of the file. Make the workflow to be triggered when file is created.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought that I could use that link as well but that link isn't an actual link just to the image, but it is a page with the image in it. Also, external sharing is disabled.

Comment: @Robin If you really want to get the original Direct link, you can use Classic experience, if you select the picture, there will be preview panel and you can get the direct URL there. Or you can use the workflow to get the URL of the image. The URL path field is a tenant relative path so you need to do a bit arrangement. The web image URL is a bit different than the direct URL